# Is there the equivalent of an "after" clause in a switch/case declaration ? JAVA

Tags: java, switch-statement, finally

I would like to know if there is a way to execute a procedure at the end of each passage through a switch/case operator in Java ? (In the case of a switch in a loop for example)

Something like this 'after' operator (which do :

```
switch (constant) {
    case a: return "x";
    case b: return "y";
    case c: return "z";
    default: return "unknown";
    after: alwayPassInThisMethodAfterBreakStatement()
}
```

I can't simply write my operation after the switch case statement because of the 'return' operation and I can't use a 'break' operation instead of 'return' because of my context.

Comment: "I can't simply write my operation after the switch case statement because of the 'return' operation" - you could do it in a `finally` block...

Comment: finally block doesn't exist in switch case, this is for try/catch

Comment: Do you *have* to return before you execute the procedure?

Comment: Yes, I have to, but someone gave me a good answer. I just have to put my afterProcedure() right after the method call that contains the switch case instruction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use try-finally to guarantee the after method is called, and this avoids repeating the call per branch. Example:

```
    try {
        switch (constant) {
           case 1: return "x";
           case 2: return "y";
           case 3: return "z";
           default: return "unknown";
        }
    } finally {
        alwaysCalledAtEnd();
    }
```

Comment: Gosh, what a circumstance! Why not  the alwaysCallAtEnd() directly after the call of afterSwitch(). It's works faster and won't cause overheads of zick-zack with the fore and back.

Comment: That rather depends on who writes the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

There is no after or finally in a switch-case statement. You could build an if-else like:

```
if(yourvar==a) {
  Alwaysmethod();
  return x;
} else if(yourvar==b) {
  Alwaysmethod();
  return y;
} else if(yourvar==c) {
  Alwaymethod();
  return z;
} ..
```

But this makes no sense. You could put the method just after your switch-case or wherever your return arives so it would always be executed.

Comment: Yes thats work when I put my code where the return arives, thank you

Comment: if (yourvar = c) never works! It's an assignment, not a conditional statement

Comment: @Joe, i have edited the example.. was more a pseudocode to get the idea , but you are right!